# How do I get my code to wait for 10 seconds but still execute something within these 10 seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a code that needs to wait 10 seconds.  During this 10 second, it needs to execute something (print off the seconds passed).  Right now it starts the timer, then proceeds to the end (prints DONE).  I can see the timer working as the number of seconds passed are still being printed off.  Running python 3.8.5 here

```
import requests
import json
import time
import warnings
import subprocess
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from ftplib import FTP
import hashlib
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading
import urllib3
from tkinter import *

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("1750+ HMI Setup App")
        self.window.geometry("550x675")
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.window.configure(bg='#34aeeb')
        self.sv = tk.StringVar()
        self.start_time = 0
        self.timecnt = 10

        self.actions()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def actions(self):
        self.counter = 0
        mode = 1
        if mode == 1:
            print("here")           
            self.start_time = time.time()
            self.start()

            if self.after_loop == None:
                pass

        print ('Done!' + "\n")  

    def start(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.timer()

    def timer(self):
        # while self.counter <=10:
        self.sv.set(round(time.time() - self.start_time))
        self.counter = self.counter + 1 
        self.after_loop = self.window.after(1000, self.timer)   
        print (self.counter)    

        if self.counter >= 10:
            self.stop()
        
    def stop(self):
        if self.after_loop is not None:
            self.window.after_cancel(self.after_loop)
            self.after_loop = None
            print (self.after_loop)

Timer()
```

Comment: You could use `after()`

Comment: Do you literally need your code to _wait_, or are you asking how to run a block of code after a delay?

Comment: @Cool Cloud - I've been using .after() like here:  self.window.after(1000, self.timer)

It's a 2 part problem.  The main code needs to execute until it gets to a timer (self.start()).  There's a 10 second timer inside.  During this 10 seconds, I need it to print out the seconds elapsed once a second.  Once the 10 seconds has passed, then continue and print DONE.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a for loop that loops 10 times and in each time the x (or whatever name variable you use) will be the number of seconds and in the loop, you wait 1 second and print x.

```
for x in range(1,11):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
```